# Is there a set of standard compiler options?

Tags: c++, gcc, qmake

I am making a project using `qmake` and I want it to be easy to compile by many users. So far I was developing only for **Linux** and only for the **gcc** compiler. I would like my project to be compilable on other platforms too.

So far I passed the compiler options (which I found in the gcc documentation) to qmake like this:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++14 \
                  -ffloat-store \
                  -O3 \
```

But then I realized that these options may not be valid on other compilers and tried to find equivalent options for other popular compilers, such as **clang** or **Intel**. To my surprise I found out that:

1. The optimization options `-O0, -O1, -O2, -O3` are common to all three compilers.
2. The `-std=c++11` and `-std=c++14` options are common to **gcc** and **clang**
3. As far as I know, `-ffloat-store` and some other options are present only in **gcc**.

I wonder, is there some set of options, that is either formally or informally standard?

Comment: The only compiler option I have seen for all C++ compilers I have used so far is the `E` option to get preprocessed code. Even that is spelled `-E` for all sane compilers and `/E` for another one.

Comment: You can use [Conditionals](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-advanced-usage.html) for the options for each platform/compiler. The only buildin qmake has out of your three options is `CONFIG += c++11`

Comment: -D and -I are also pretty common IIRC (of course, that's /D and /I on Windows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

POSIX defines something about the [c99](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) command (but AFAIK nothing about C++).

However, the [qmake](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-manual.html) utility will usually be able to find out (or at least to expect) what is the C++ compiler and how to invoke it. Notice that it is generating a `Makefile`

Outside of Qt you might consider [cmake](http://www.cmake.org/) or [autoconf](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/). They both generate `Makefile`-s.

See also [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/273235/40065) (on [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/)).

Answer (score 1):

No.

The C++ standard doesn't cover any compiler option. This is something that can vary wildly between different implementations (or even different versions of the same implementation).

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head, there's almost nothing in common between the major compilers.

The truth is, any non-trivial project requires some fine-tuning both in-code and the build process when you're aiming for multiple platforms. Your best bet is in my experience (and this is largely opinion-based), to craft the build process for each compiler to be as simple as possible, and fix most of the 'quirks' via pragmas in a platform/compiler specific include file that you "auto-include" everywhere.

Comment: That is about the worst idea how to approach multi platform targeting. What you really have to do is identify platform dependent and platform independent code. Then make your design such that platform dependent code is in separate files and has a good, stable API and is minimal. Then you implement that for each  platform you want to support and you need no auto-include or #ifdef stuff in your code base at all. Then you use cmake or alike and you can build multi platform, linking the splatform specific code for the platform you build.

Comment: I totally agree: keep platform code in separate files which are of course completely ignored in the other platforms, use implementation hiding patterns, etc. Never use #ifdefs for stuff like this, it's just a mess.

That said, leveraging compilers with different levels of C++ support, and toning down/up their respective idiosyncrasies regarding warnings and errors does require some trickery sometimes.